# Сильное и слабое управление - в чем разница?

Tags: управление

В учебниках как-то невнятно описывается разница между сильным и слабым управлением. На сколько я понял, сильное управление это некое обобщение переходности у глаголов:

> Основной признак слабого управления: зависимое слово (его падеж,
> лексическое значение) вариативно и не определяется глаголом (сравните
> сильное управление-писать письмо (переходный глагол требует В. п.) и
> слабое управление - писать ручкой (чем? как?), писать на столе ( на
> чём? где?), писать в журнал (во что? куда?).

Чтож, давайте попробуем разобраться на примерах:

```
Как добраться до врача? //сильное управление, приставка совпадает с прелогом
Как добраться к врачу? //слабое? 
Подозревал об этом // сильное? Почему, ведь есть вариативность?
Подозревал это //сильное управление, винительный падеж
Зайти за дом //сильное (приставка совпадает с предлогом)
Зайти в дом //слабое? Почему?
```

Comment: Возможно, сильное управление это ответы на вопросы что, за что, чем, о чем, до кого? - то есть когда вопрос содержит личное местоимение. А слабое это вопросы: когда, куда, где и тд, когда местоимения нет. Зайти за что? - За дом, сильное. Зайти не во что, а куда? - в дом, слабое. Приехать в каком месяце? - приехать в августе, сильное. Домик где? - домик в деревне, слабое. Правда, работать над рефератом,слабое - работать как?? Работать реферат - сильное.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474701/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be